# Selenium WebDriver. Entered value for Input field was cut for some unknown reason

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I’m trying to enter certain values into the Login form:

```
| username | password      | 
| admin    | adminpassword |
```

I send the values into the input fields with the following java code using Selenium Webdriver v.3 and **geckodriver for Firefox**:

```
for (User user : users) {
    base.driver.findElement(By.name("UserName")).sendKeys(user.username);
    base.driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(user.password); }
```

and as a result I see on UI:

> **User**:     *admin*
>
> **Password**: *adminpas*

Sure, test fails, as password is incorrect. I don’t understand **why the value was cut** from *adminpassword* to *adminpas*?
Moreover, each time I run the test: it cut diff number of characters.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you would send the password character by character? `for (int i=0; i<user.password.length; ++i) {base.driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(user.password.charAt(i));}`

Comment: Have you tried to add a delay after sendKeys(user.password)? It might be sending the enter before the password send has completed.

Comment: @Gábor, such code sample can not be resolved because of '.sendKeys(user.password.charAt(i))' part

Comment: @klitz1967, I've tried to add 'Thread.sleep(2000);' just as a one-time solution, but it didn't help

Comment: @NatiSunny maybe `sendKeys(user.password.charAt(i).toString());`? I'm without a compiler at the moment.

Comment: first of all - define where is the problem. I would write simple same test 1. without cucumber 2. without datadriven approach. In order to narrow the number of probable roots of the problem. Then try with different browsers (chrome vs firefox). Then try with sleeps. With sleeps before and after. Also try to set value via javascript directly. A lot of things can be tried like that in context of debug ;)

Comment: @yashaka, after investigation it looks like 'application' problem, the same project works fine with Amazon similar functionality. Additionally, problem exists in both: Firefox and Chrome browsers. Sleeps didn't help, so I'm trying the last idea :) -> javascript piece of code proposed by "yong" below.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Check it will happen on other browser

If yes, go to  point 2 at below

If no, check the webdriver is compatible with browser, try different webdriver version

**2)** Check any key event binded to the password box

In same case, developer bind key event to check illegal input or check the system has such user in background by Ajax before user click login or do something else.

If yes, the key event break the normal sendKeys, try set the password by javascript in backgroud:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

String script = "arguments[0].value=arguments[1]";
WebElement passwordBox = driver.findElement(By.name("Password"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(script, passwordBox, user.password);

// send a space or TAB to trigger key event
passwordBox.sendKeys(" ");   
// passwordBox.sendKeys(Key.TAB);
```

If no, back to point 1, try on different combination of webdriver and browser

```
//pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version> // you can change to other version
</dependency>
```

Comment: please advise what artefact should I use for maven dependency in order to use JavaScriptExecutor class? I've tried a few Intellij idea proposed, but no one resolved executeScript() method

Comment: this is its package path `org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor`, it together with class `WebDriver` and 'By'. So I think you should include this jar into project. You can explore that jar to see it includes this class